# SQLite upgrade issue

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade

I have 2 classes: `TableA` and `TableB`, corresponding to the SQLite tables in the first version of my App.
Now I am ready to release the next version, where I have to add another table, `TableC`.

In each class, I have an `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase)` and `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion)` method.

Here is what I want to do: keep **TableA** as it is,
add a new column to **TableB**
and, of course, create a new **TableC**.

I have updated my Database version number in the **SQLiteOpenHelper**
I have my methods implemented as below:

```
TableA.onUpgrade(/*parameters*/){
  //Nothing to do here
}

TableB.onUpgrade(/*parameters*/){
  sqlDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TableB ADD COLUMN columnFoo INTEGER DEFAULT 1");
}

TableC.onUpgrade(/*parameters*/){
  sqlDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
  onCreate(sqlDatabase); //calls sqlDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TableC);
}
```

My SQLiteOpenHelper subclass implementation looks as below:

```
     @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase) {
    TableA.onCreate(sqlDatabase);
    TableB.onCreate(sqlDatabase);
            TableC.onCreate(sqlDatabase);
 }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion)         
      {
    TableA.onUpgrade(sqlDatabase);
    TableB.onUpgrade(sqlDatabase);
            TableC.onUpgrade(sqlDatabase);
  }
```

My problem is that I am having trouble testing this.
When I installed the new version of my app on a fresh Genymotion Android VM, I got an error on a query which I do in my Launch activity on **TableB**, saying that **the new column does not exist**.

I tested by upgrading on an existing Genymotion Android VM which had version 1 of my app installed.
There it seemed to work fine.

I certainly can go on creating new VM's for every run, and installing my app to test.
But I wanted to ask what I could be doing wrong, and what would be a good way to test.
How do I correctly handle updating the database for my existing users, and how do I create new database/tables for my new users?
Any help is appreciated!!

My App supports Android API 14 (ICS) and above.

Comment: When are you calling your onUpgrade method as it sounds like in your post you are calling it _always_.

Comment: I am assuming that the SQLLiteOpenHelper `onUpdate()` is called whenever the database version number defined in that class is incremented.

Comment: Apologies, I checked the code for SQLLiteOpenHelper and it does manage onUpdate() for you. Which API level of Android are you testing on and  are you deleting the app and reinstalling for version 1 to version 2 testing.

Comment: App has api level 14 and above :). Testing on Api 18. I tried upgrading from v1 to v2, which worked fine, but a fresh install on a new vm did not work, with the above mentioned error..

Comment: Figured the issue. The onCreate() method for TableB had a missing `,` in the SQL query syntax. MY BAD!! I cannot believe I wasted my entire afternoon on this. Thanks for anyone who read through this question. I will delete it after some time so as to not waste anyones time. :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem happens when device #1 have app db version lets say 2, device #2 have app db version 5, and new release have db version 6.

Then ideally:
device 1 should start upgrade from 2->3->4->5->6.
device 2: 5->6.

So old upgrade code stay intact, and you keep adding new upgrade code for new version.

Here is an example (one of the way to handle onUpgrade()):

```
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     try {
            if (oldVersion < 51) {
                upgradeToVersion51(db); // From 50 or 51
                oldVersion = 51;
            }
            if (oldVersion == 51) {
                upgradeToVersion52(db);
                oldVersion += 1;
            }
            if (oldVersion == 52) {
                upgradeToVersion53(db);
                oldVersion += 1;
            }

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onUpgrade: SQLiteException, recreating db. ", e);
            Log.e(TAG, "(oldVersion was " + oldVersion + ")");
            return; // this was lossy
        }    
  }
```

Note: you need to bump  static final int DATABASE_VERSION; whenever you upgrade, check this link for example.

Check how Calendar handles db upgrade here: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarDatabaseHelper.java/?v=source

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :). I found out that one of my sql queries had a `,` missing! The implementation works fine!